# Real time emailing notification using PHP and Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

A client wanted a feature in his website that would notify the users through email or a text message **30 minutes** before the schedule of his/her lesson.

My knowledge of *PHP* and *JQUERY* is constricted to - the functions of PHP will only be triggered when someone viewed or visited the page. My approach to achieve this was to check the time and then send the email if `time()` is 30 minutes before the schedule of a particular user.

The problem of course is the system cannot do a check if nobody visits the page, or even handle the notification the way we want which is and should be **real time.**

I'm looking forward for solutions and enlightenment or methods to achieve my goal. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a Cron job for it. First create a separate PHP file where you put in all your logic to send email to the users. After your file is created, you need to automate it so that server runs this PHP file for you on your mentioned intervals, let's say every 5 minutes, 30 minutes, hour or so on..

If you are on shared hosting then you must have cPanel with it. Have a look at this link for Cron Job guide. [[Link]](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/Cron+Jobs)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a cron job (Linux servers) or a scheduled task (Windows servers). See here for documentation http://www.thesitewizard.com/general/set-cron-job.shtml

Setup a cron job to periodcically run one of your PHP files which runs the checks to determine if emails should be sent.